# ARIMA throws TypeError: ARIMA.fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'trend'

Tags: python

Full text of all code is below:

```
import pandas as pdimport numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import warningswarnings.filterwarnings("ignore")  
file_path = '/Users/doyeongpark/Downloads/BTCprice.csv'bitcoin_df = pd.read_csv(file_path, names = ['day', 'price'])  
bitcoin_df.tail()  
bitcoin_df['day'] = pd.to_datetime(bitcoin_df['day'])  
bitcoin_df.index = bitcoin_df['day']bitcoin_df.set_index('day', inplace=True)bitcoin_df.head()  
bitcoin_df.describe()`  
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMAimport statsmodels.api as sm  
model = ARIMA(bitcoin_df.price.values, order=(2,1,2))model_fit = model.fit(trend = 'c',full_output = True, disp = True)

print(model_fit.summary())

in the code


model = ARIMA(bitcoin_df.price.values, order=(2,1,2))model_fit = model.fit(trend = 'c',full_output = True, disp = True)
```

seems to be throwing an error:TypeError: ARIMA.fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'trend'

Looking at the referenced Youtube video, it works fine, why am I the only one like this?

https://youtu.be/AuzoQ8eZXEw